# Access Client clipboard from server in java/jsf/primefaces

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Problem description : user press print screen button and then click on paste button on application. That image will be store on server.

I googled and find answer on Stack over and used following code

```
public Image getImageFromClipboard()
{

Clipboard systemClipboard = (Clipboard) AccessController.doPrivileged(new PrivilegedAction() {
    public Object run() 
    {
        Clipboard tempClipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
     return tempClipboard;
    }

});


// get the contents on the clipboard in a 
// Transferable object
Transferable clipboardContents = systemClipboard.getContents(null);

// check if contents are empty, if so, return null
if (clipboardContents == null)
    return null;
else
    try
    {
        // make sure content on clipboard is 
        // falls under a format supported by the 
        // imageFlavor Flavor
        if (clipboardContents.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.imageFlavor))
        {
            // convert the Transferable object
            // to an Image object
            Image image = (Image) clipboardContents.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
            return image;
        }
    } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException ufe)
    {
        ufe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe)
    {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
/*try {
Robot robot;

    robot = new Robot();

final GraphicsConfiguration config
    = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment()
          .getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
final BufferedImage screenshot = robot.createScreenCapture(config.getBounds());
return screenshot;
} catch (AWTException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}*/
return null;
}
```

This code work well if application is running on my machine and I press Print Screen. Image is available and store.

My problem is that when I am deploying this application on separate server and run application on another machine. When user press Print screen and then click on button in application. Server won't find any image because it look on clipboard and on server clipboard no image is available. Image is available on Client desktop clipboard.

Kindly help me to access Client clipboard from server using JSF/primefaces. Or other alternative way.

I am using primefaces 3.4, server is weblogic 10.3.5.

Comment: There is not way to access client clipboard with just JavaScript (if this would be possible it will be mayor security problem). Possible workaround would be to use Flash. As I'm not familiar with Flash I post this as a comment.

Comment: Replace "JSF/PrimeFaces" by "JavaScript" in your search keywords.

Answer (score 0):

If your application will be running on different browsers, you will find no 100% reliable way of doing it unless you implement some specific component with some other technology like Flash.

I would really use the approach of saving the image and uploading it to the server via a normal file upload form. Else you will be having headaches with Browser security issues.

Regards